# How to call a variable from the login form in the main form?

Tags: c#, forms, variables, authentication

I have a login form and when the login is successful the login form closes and the main form opens with this code in my program.cs

```
    Login fLogin = new Login();
        if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            main = new Main();
            Application.Run(main);
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

and with this code in the login form

```
    if (login == true)
                {
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                }
```

When the Main Form opens I want to show the email I used to login in a messagebox. I tried creating a variable with the email before the DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; and then callint it in the main form but it doesn't work.
Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a property in Main Form

In main form

```
  class Main: Form{
        public string Username{get;set;}
    }
```

Assign when login success

```
if (fLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            main = new Main();
            main.Username = fLogin.UsernameText;
            Application.Run(main);
        }
```